# GPS arrow could not disappear at iPhone's status bar in our released app version

Tags: ios, gps, power-management

We developed an app which uses the GPS service of iOS 4.0+.
Once you leave our app, such as when you return to the iPhone home screen or shift to other app, the GPS would be updated in every 10 mins at background for our app.

In our development phase, the GPS arrow would disappear just after leaving our app,
but what we are encountering now is that in the release version(downloaded from AppStore), the arrow is always showing in the status bar!
So, the battery cost is more than we expected.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replied by Apple tech center:

This is not possible. Your app can use Region Monitoring to be "woken up" when a user enters or leads an area http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13.
Or it can declare itself a navigation app, and keep the GPS radio turned on the entire time.
This is what an app giving turn-by-turn driving directions would do. However this drains a lot of power.